# La voix passive ou la voix active

Tags: verbes-pronominaux, passif

While doing a test, I encountered the following question:

> Le rôle du directeur _________ par un comédien amateur.

And I wonder which of these answers is correct:

- `est joué`
- `se joue`

On one hand, `est joué` is the passive voice of verb `jouer` and the actor is the one, who does the action, on the other hand I know that reflexive verbs are sometimes used to display passive voice. So I wonder: which of these two is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*est joué* is the correct answer. I’m not able to give you a reason why you couldn’t use a reflexive verb, but one example where *se joue* can be used is "Le rôle du directeur se joue facilement".

Answer (score 2):

The reason you cannot use a reflexive when the object is explicitly stated is that it would cause said object to appear both as a noun and as a pronoun, which is normally considered an error of syntax.

Compare it to a phrase like "*Le rôle du directeur _____ différemment de nos jours*" where both the reflexive and passive voice are possible.